# Is there a Markdown editor for Dojo

Tags: dojo, markdown

Is there a good [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) editor for [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)?

I have seen [Control.TextArea](http://livepipe.net/control/textarea) (based on Prototype) and [Stack Overflow's reverse-engineered version of WMD](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/) (seems to rely on jQuery) but I'd rather use a Dojo-based tool, as my site already uses this framework.

Does such a tool exist? Googling for [dojo markdown editor](http://www.google.com/search?q=dojo+markdown+editor) doesn't seem to return any useful results, apart from a Google Summer of Code 2008 student [blogging that he's working on it](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/2008/07/06/markdown-parser-progressing)...

Comment: How was the quality of the GSOC dojox markup editor?

Comment: Haven't had time to look at it, and don't think I'll have in the near future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the work done by Dojo's GSoC 2008 student here:

```
svn co http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/soc/2008/markup_apopelo
```

For some reason it was not integrated into DojoX proper — I cannot vouch for the quality of the code. I can see that it is supposed to support Markdown, Mediawiki, and Textile.

Take a look, and let us know if it is any good, and what is missing, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't had any time to check that out yet, but to be honest I would really prefer to have some kind of "official" editor, even if it means steering away from Dojo. Anyway, I'll give it a look when possible and report on the quality of the thing.